# Suggested formula for curving test results

Tags: fractions

Take a test score represented by the fraction ${a\over b}$.  This test score could be curved by removing a wrong answer to get ${a\over b-1}$ or adding a correct answer to get ${a+1\over b+1}$.  Sometimes the former will cause a greater increase to the fraction, sometimes the latter will cause a greater increase, and sometimes they will be equal.  For example

${99\over 100}$ would become either  ${99\over 99}$ or ${100\over 101}$ (a is better)

${1\over 3}$ would become either ${1\over 2}$ or ${2\over 4}$, (same)

${0\over 3}$ would become either ${0\over 2}$ or ${1\over 4}$ (b is better)

Is there a formula for at which points or intervals one way is better than the other? (Equal would be at $-a^2 + ab + a = 1$)

Comment: in the second line, do you mean $a \over b-1$?

Comment: @Sabyasachi thanks

Comment: Your formula for both being the same can't work. $-a^2 + ab + a = 1$ means that $a$ is a factor of $1$, therefore $a$ can only be $1$. Since $2\over 5$ gives the same result either way, this doesn't work. In this case, $-a^2 + ab + a = 8$ which is a multiple of $a=2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$${a\over b-1}\gt \frac{a+1}{b+1}$$

$$ab+a\gt ab+b-a-1\implies b\lt 2a+1$$

If $b$ is less than $2a+1$ the first is better. If it is equal, both options are equal. If it is more, then, the second option is better.

Answer (score 2):

We need to solve $$\frac{a}{b-1}>\frac{a+1}{b+1} $$or
$$ {a}(b+1)> (a+1)(b-1),$$which is
$$  2a > b -1.$$